# Why is there a syntax failure on a HTML/React page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Here is a set of examples put together that are purported to work.

I'm just diving into React and I think this page should work, but it doesn't.
It fails at "return

```
<script>
    window.onload = function()
    {
        class App extends React.Component
        {
            constructor()
            {
                super();
                this.state = {value: ''};
                this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
            }

            onChange(e)
            {
                const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
                if (e.target.value === '' || re.test(e.target.value)) 
                {
                    this.setState({value: e.target.value})
                }
            }

            render()
            {
                return <input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            }
        }

        ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))

}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you show the error message showing on console ?

Comment: have you added react.js library, If yes need your full html page rather than just script

Comment: JSX needs to be compiled before it can be executed in the browser

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App),document.getElementById('app'))` [react without jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Answer (score 1):

JSX cannot be executed in the browser. You need to compile it to regular javascript before executing.

JSX is the HTML-like syntax, like: "< Component />". This is a special form of javascript.

There are various ways to compile JSX, but the most common are with Babel, or with the TypeScript compiler.

Read more on the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use JSX syntax (specifically `<input value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>`) inside a plain `<script>` element. It needs converting to JavaScript using Babel (and preferably at build time rather than after it reaches the browser) before the browser can understand it.

This is covered [at the start of the React Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-for-the-tutorial).